# Ajax get php data every x second with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('ajax.php', function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
}, 5000);
```

I found this code. But this is not enough for me.. I want this like this. I dont know javascript. I could have some mistake.. I writing this to make you understand.

```
function getdata(getdatafrom, resultclass){
    $.get('getdatafrom', function(data) {
        $('resultclass').html(data);
    });
}
```

When I use it:

```
setInterval(getdata('get.php?action=test','.resultclass'), 5000);
```

I ll use this scipt.

I want to use code like this, cause I ll get a lot of stuff and I want to run at one code for develop eaisly.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Change:  `$('resultclass').html(data);` to: `$(resultclass).html(data);`.

Comment: You just need to remove quotes inside your `getdata` function, from `'getdatafrom'` and `'resultclass'`.

Comment: When trying to make it more functional, you broke it.

Comment: I was said I could have some mistake. I was wrote here the new code to show you what I want but I was wrote correctly almost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be as following :

```
function getdata(getdatafrom, resultclass){
    $.get(getdatafrom, function(data) {
        $(resultclass).html(data);
    });
}
```

By removing the single quote `'` arround the variables it should works fine.

```
function getdata(getdatafrom, resultclass){
    $.get('getdatafrom', function(data) {
__________^___________^
        $('resultclass').html(data);
__________^___________^
    });
}
```

When you're using the single quotes `'` the variables (`getdatafrom` and `resultclass`) considered as strings.

If you don't want to wait 5 seconds for the first time you could call `getdata`  by adding the following line just before `setInterval()` :

```
getdata('get.php?action=test','.resultclass')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @KevinB, you can't invoke getData in place like that and expect it to fire for every interval. All your comment's code is doing is firing the function once. you'll need to `bind` the values to the function or execute it IN the callback function.

Comment: @Seth i was pointing out what was in the question, and missing from this answer.. :)

Comment: the answer was updated to provide a fix, so the comment was no longer relevant.

Comment: Works well thank you. But when I open page, It waits 5 seconds to show result at the first time. I want to show the first time with NO WAIT after that refresh every 5 second.

Comment: Can you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775424/ajax-post-with-function

Comment: Hi @user3715993 I posted an answer for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775424/ajax-post-with-function/36793013#36793013

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
      getdata('get.php?action=test','.resultclass')
}, 5000);

function getdata(getdatafrom, resultclass){
    $.get(getdatafrom, function(data) {
         $(resultclass).html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the `resultclass` parameter