# Ajax POST with function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was using this code for get function and It works perfectly. Im getting data with this function.

```
    function getdata(getdatafrom, resultclass){
    $.get(getdatafrom, function(data) {
        $(resultclass).html(data);
    });
}
```

But I need this for post method. Im getting inputs with this get method I have to post it. It has to look like this.

```
function postdata(postdatafrom, inputnamesvaluelist){
    $.post(postdatafrom, function(data) {
        $(resultclass).html(data);
    });
}
```

I will enter input names on this code like :

```
onclick="postdata(post.php,input1-input2-input3)"
```

And it ll post this inputs.. How can I do this?

Comment: `resultclass` is `undefined` in the `postdata` function, unless it is defined elsewhere, while in the `getdata` function it is explicitly passed as a parameter. Is it intended? Besides, is the server actually ready to handle the post request correctly?

Comment: no no I dont want any result class?  It ll change to input names to post it.. Like I was give onclick="" example..

Comment: I'm havign trouble understanding what you're trying to do, but wouldn't you want to include some data with your post request? `$.post(postdatafrom, inputnamesvaluelist, function(data) {...`
[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: `inputnamesvaluelist` - if you meant values -  I'll lost the input names in such case. For ex. : if you pass only input values in random order - how do you know which value is "email" or "firstname" ? Can you your html markup with those input?

Comment: Yeah I know that thats why befour post function you have inputnamesvaluelist variable. you should get ready inputs for .post function..

Comment: No I meant input names or id's to define inputs, look values and understand what to send.

Comment: Think like this if we use input id's -> postdata(post.php,#input1-#input2-#input3)

Answer (score 1):

If you would do this using inline-event you should add single quotes :

```
onclick="postdata('post.php', '#input1-#input2-#input3')"
```

Then your js should be :

```
function postdata(postdatafrom, inputnamesvaluelist){
    var inputs_ids = inputnamesvaluelist.split('-');//split string passed into array of ids
    var parameters={};

    //construct obejct of {name: value,..} that you could pass it in post request
    $.each(inputs_ids, function(index, input_id){
        var input_name  = $(input_id).attr("name");
        var input_value = $(input_id).val();

        parameters[input_name]=input_value;
    })

    //post parameters to given "postdatafrom"
    $.post(postdatafrom, parameters, function(data) {
        //Your code here
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.